# Correlation between input for Neural Network for bankruptcy prediction

Tags: r, neural-network, correlation

So, i have 24 financial input or variable for my neural network for me to predict bankruptcy for a firm in R. The question is, since neural network is a black box model, do we still need to remove any inter-correlated input before we build the neural network? sorry, i know this is a simple question but an undergraduate like me find it tough to grasp the idea of black box method.

Comment: consider moving this to stats.stackexchange, see https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/232534/does-correlated-input-data-lead-to-overfitting-with-neural-networks

Comment: So do you mean input that can be calculated by other input? So example: [amount of items sold, price per item, money earned by selling items] you mean?